# Sql Server Insert query Into multiple tables from temporary tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables one is master and another one is details table , Details table contain master table id as reference

Here is my table

```
**Table_Customer**  
CustomerId  CustomerName
1           A
2           B

**Table_CustomerRelatives**         
RelativesId  CustomerId     RelativesName   Address
1                  1                M        xyz
2                  1                N        mno
3                  2                L        pqr
4                  2                O        ghy
```

Here CustomerId and RelativesId are identity columns so automatic generating columnvalue

Here I have two temp tables like

```
**TembreryTableCustomer**   
CustomerId  CustomerName
1               F
2               G
3               H

**TembreryTableDetails**        
CustomerId  RelativesName   Address
1              S             fgg
1              T             dfg
2              U             ghj
3              V             jkl
3              W             rty
```

How can Insert Temp table data to my tables with identity.
here i want to insert rows of temp table customer and get identity value then insert temp table details data using temp table customer identity.

Comment: Have a look at SCOPE_IDENTITY in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `output` clause of the `merge` statement to build a mapping of the temporary customer's id to the new id.

```
declare @Map table (Old int, New int);

;merge  Table_Customer dest
using   TembreryTableCustomer src
on      dest.CustomerName = src.CustomerName
when    not matched then
        insert (CustomerName) values (CustomerName)
output  inserted.CustomerID, src.CustomerID
into    @map;

insert  Table_CustomerRelatives
        (CustomerId, RelativesName, Address)
select  m.New
,       t.RelativesName
,       t.Address
from    TembreryTable2 t
join    @Map m
on      t.CustomerID = m.Old;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c567/1/1)

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches depending on the version of SQL and your preference for where to put the work.

I find using [sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx) far easier to use than identity columns.  You can use the same sequence in your temp tables as in your persistent tables so there's no "fixup" to do.

Barring that, you can insert into the persistent table with an [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.100).aspx) clause to capture the newly assigned IDs.  From the link, check out example "E".  The salient feature is to output persistent IDs alongside the temp table IDs.

Comment: You cannot use the `output` clause of the `insert` statement to get the temp table id. Try it.

Comment: Aw crud - that's what I get for an off-handed answer!  @Andomar, You're right of course.